# Elasticsearch "keep_types" filter doesn't work with "pattern" tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I am having a problem using the "keep_types" filter with a "pattern" tokenizer, here is an example:

```
    {
        "tokenizer": {
            "type": "pattern",
            "pattern": "[()., _-]"
        },
        "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            {
                "type": "keep_types",
                "types": [
                    "<ALPHANUM>"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "text": [
            "7002982065_8031949292_Bomba (Vácuo,pressão) - Suryha.pdf"
        ]
    }
```

The result against the _analyze API is:

```
  {
    "tokens": []
  }
```

If I remove the keep_types it works as intended.

I also noted it works fine if I use the "standard" analyzer, but in this case, it wouldn't tokenize the text in the desired way.

I am using version 6.8, but also  tried in 7.5 with same results...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get to the intendend result using the "letter" tokenizer, it removes numbers and quotes without the need of filters.

```
{
    "tokenizer": {
        "type": "letter"
    },
    "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
    ],
    "text": [
        "7002982065_8031949292_Bomba (\"Vácuo,pressão) - Suryha.pdf"
    ]
}
```

the result is

```
[
  "bomba",
  "vacuo",
  "pressao",
  "suryha",
  "pdf"
]
```

But I still think it is worth answering the main question, so I will keep it open